Width of a convex body is $\geq 1$ if and only if it contains a unit segment in every direction
Let $K$ be a convex body (compact with nonempty interior).
For any direction $a$ let $w(K,a)$ be the width of the thinnest strip (aka slab or plank) that contains $K$ with where the hyperplanes of the strip have normal vectors parallel to $a$. We define the width of $K$, denoted by $w(K) = \inf\{w(K,a) \ : \ a \in S^{d-1}\}$. (In short, $w(K)$ is the thinnest strip that contains $K$.)
I have been trying to prove the following statement:
For $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a convex body, $w(K) \geq 1$ if and only if $K$ contains a unit segment in every direction.
With regards to proving the direction $(\implies)$:
My main ideas have been as follows:
Idea 1: Let $a$ be a unit vector. Consider the convex bodies $K + \frac12 a$ and $K - \frac12 a$.
Observe that
\begin{align*}
   \left((K + \frac12 a\right) \cap \left(K - \frac12 a\right) \neq \varnothing &\iff 
   x_1 + \frac{1}{2}a = x_2 - \frac12 a \quad \text{for some $x_1,x_2 \in K$} \\ 
   &\iff x_2 - x_1 = a,
\end{align*}
giving us that $[x_1,x_2]$ has length $1$ in direction $a$, as desired. So what is left to show is that $\left((K + \frac12 a\right) \cap \left(K - \frac12 a\right) \neq \varnothing$. If they are disjoint then we can use the hyperplane separation theorem to say that there exists a hyperplane strictly separating the two translates of $K$. This hyperlane has to have a normal a normal vector $n$. I then tried to force a contradiction from here but couldn't quite figure out how to.
Idea 2: Consider the longest segment contained in $K$ in the direction $a$. Let $x$ and $y$ be the endpoints of this segment. It's not too hard to show that $x$ and $y$ must lie on the boundary. I would like to then show that they have supporting hyperplanes that are parallel (which would then essentially finish the argument). This is intuitively clear as, otherwise, one could shift the segment inside the convex body and then extend the shifted segment to get a longer segment. The only problem is, if there are multiple supporting hyperplanes then it's not clear how to write this argument down carefully. For instance, what if $x$ (say) is the vertex of a polytope, in which case many of the shifts of the segment $[x,y]$ could cause the segment to no longer be contained in the convex body.
Any advice on either of these two directions (or on any different directions) would be greatly appreciated.

Here’s a rough sketch of how you can proceed with idea 1.
Without loss of generality, assume $K$ is closed. Let $K_+$ and $K_-$ be the two shifted sets, and let $C$ be their union. Since $C$ is closed, it’s complement is open, so you can find two distinct parallel hyperplanes $H_+$ and $H_-$, both separating $K_+$ and $K_-$, such that $H_\pm$ is the supporting hyperplane of $K_\pm$ and their normals are $a$. Now shift the two sets along with their supporting hyperplanes back to $K$. The shifted hyperplanes form a slab thinner than $1$ containing $K$, a contradiction!

Thanks so much for your response! I'm a bit confused on how you are obtaining $H_+$ and $H_-$ from the fact that the complement of $C$ is open.

@JGJ7 The Wikipedia entry on hyperplane separation theorem discusses this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem. Basically, there is a gap between the two sets and you can fit infinitely many hyperplanes in that gap. But we just need two that support the two closed convex sets.

Ah yes but we don't necessarily have control over the normal vectors of the separating hyperplane (you can trace through the proof and get that it is in the direction of the segment $[x,y]$ where $|x-y|$ is the minimum distance between the two convex sets for $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ say). But I don't think we can say that the normal vector is $a$.

Oh wait I think I see now. We can get two supporting hyperplanes with normal vectors $n$ (not necessarily the direction of the translate $a$). Then all that is left to check is that the distance between the supporting hyperplanes after the shift is less than $1$.

@JGJ7 That’s actually okay because if their normals aren’t $a$, then the shifted hyperplanes have an even smaller gap than $1$. So the argument still goes through.

@JGJ7 That’s right. Essentially, if you take two identical hyperplanes and translate one of them by a unit vector, then the distance between them is always at most $1$. It is $1$ if the translation is along the normal, but it’s strictly less than $1$ otherwise.

Ah yes I see now! Thank you for your patience.
